# google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Field number 0 is illegal while using tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(4,))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, python-embedding

C++ code, I need to build model and use python embedding, but i got this:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import tensorflow as tf");
    PyRun_SimpleString("tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()");
    PyRun_SimpleString("tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(4,))");
    return 0;
}

i got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./python-3.9_x86_64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "./python-3.9_x86_64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/message.py", line 199, in ParseFromString
    return self.MergeFromString(serialized)
  File "./python-3.9_x86_64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1106, in MergeFromString
    if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:
  File "./python-3.9_x86_64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1156, in InternalParse
    raise message_mod.DecodeError('Field number 0 is illegal.')
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Field number 0 is illegal.
```

pip freeze, libs' versions:

absl-py==1.4.0

astunparse==1.6.3

beautifulsoup4==4.12.2

cachetools==5.3.1

certifi==2023.7.22

charset-normalizer==3.2.0

flatbuffers==23.5.26

gast==0.4.0

google==3.0.0

google-auth==2.19.1

google-auth-oauthlib==1.0.0

google-pasta==0.2.0

grpcio==1.57.0

h5py==3.9.0

idna==3.4

importlib-metadata==6.6.0

jax==0.4.11

joblib==1.2.0

keras==2.13.1

Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2

libclang==16.0.0

Markdown==3.4.3

MarkupSafe==2.1.3

ml-dtypes==0.2.0

numpy==1.24.3

oauthlib==3.2.2

opt-einsum==3.3.0

packaging==23.1

protobuf==4.24.1

pyasn1==0.5.0

pyasn1-modules==0.3.0

requests==2.31.0

requests-oauthlib==1.3.1

rsa==4.9

scikit-learn==1.2.2

scipy==1.10.1

six==1.15.0

soupsieve==2.4.1

tb-nightly==2.15.0a20230815

tensorboard==2.13.0

tensorboard-data-server==0.7.1

tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1

tensorflow==2.13.0

tensorflow-estimator==2.13.0

tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.33.0

tensorrt==8.6.1

termcolor==2.3.0

threadpoolctl==3.1.0

typing-extensions==4.5.0

urllib3==1.26.16

Werkzeug==2.3.4

wrapt==1.15.0

zipp==3.15.0

Comment: This is not the full code, it is missing includes, after fixing that, I get a different error: NameError: name 'tf' is not defined. As I have said before, you have to include a fully working example that reproduces the problem in your question.

Comment: After running the updated code, I get no error, are you sure the problem is with python embedding, and not with your python installation itself?

Comment: what version of python do you use? I tried different (3.9.6 and 3.9.5)

Comment: You should answer what I asked, does this code actually work in your python installation outside embedding? I don't think python versions matter here.

Comment: It works outside embedding

Comment: How it can be problem with python embedding? because only this function fails

Comment: We cannot reproduce the problem, so likely it is a problem with your local setup, for example, having multiple python environments.